# Smarty offers file download instead of rendering html

Tags: php, smarty

I'm having a strange issue where in some cases Smarty makes the browser download an empty file instead of rendering the html. This only happens sporadically and on specific pages and depending on de (dynamic) data on the page the problem does or does not occur. 99% of the pages that use the same template work just fine. I can't put my finger on where it exactly fails to render the page and why it does offer a file download.

This problem only occurs on only one of our production servers, so I suspect the issue is server related.

There are a few things that seem te resolve the issue, but these are not permanent fixes:

- Decreasing the memory_limit to under ~15MB. This weirdly seems to fix it sometimes.
- Removing some random keys from an array that is loaded into the template. Again, this depend entirely on the contents of the array of that specific item.
- Removing the compiled template in /tmp/compile/. This makes the page load once. Then the template is compiled and then on the next page load the problem reoccurs.

This I tried but had no effect:

- Updating Smarty to the latest version
- Adding application/x-httpd-php headers to .htaccess
- Increasing the memory_limit

PHP version: 7.4.32
Smarty version: 4.3.0

**Update:**

It looks like this issue has something to do with PHP notices inside the templates. I don't understand why exactly, but the issue seems te be resolved by disabling notices like this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: How about actually downloading the file and looking what's inside? That should give you a clue about what's not running.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As I stated in my question, the file is completely empty.

Comment: I also encountered this issue today. Using Smarty 3.1.13 and PHP 5.6.
I resolved the issue by identifying a piece of code in a template that was causing it and commenting it out. But that code was being used in other places in the same template where it worked fine.
I was also assigning a "debug" variable to Smarty. Once I removed that it also fixed the issue. Even though that variable was not used anywhere inside the template.
So it does not make any sense to me. I suspect its a parse bug.